# How to key in a prime in Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do you key in a prime or double primes in Adobe illustrator in a textbox?
I am using Wins7 system.

Comment: Windows or Mac? In [Windows you can use this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/using-special-characters-character-map-faq#1TC=windows-7), or [use this if you know what the hex code is](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm), but I don't know anything about Macs, I'm afraid.

Comment: The same way you’d do it anywhere else. Did you try anything out before asking here? What did you try? What did Googling tell you? Why did none of that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of any operating system, Illustrator is equipped with a "Glyphs" panel. With the textbox in edit mode, open the glyphs panel, locate the appropriate prime mark you require (double prime is usually at the beginning of the list, and prime is located after the letters) and double click on it. I use this method on a daily basis.

I just hoped that Adobe would have followed the same method as that used in InDesign – it has a shortcut.

Comment: It's those tiny differences between AI and InD that really grind my gears. For some reason (interoffice animosity? separate software review groups? bad communication?) the Glyphs panel in InD is superior over AI's in many (small) ways, even though there is *clearly* some shared code base...

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, as Paul suggested, use the `Character Map` to insert special characters into documents and text fields.

1. Open the `Start Menu`
2. Type `Character Map` and hit return.
3. Select the appropriate typeface in the `Character Map` application.
4. Find the special character you want
5. Click `Select` and then `Copy`
6. Paste in your field or document.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/using-special-characters-character-map-faq#1TC=windows-7

---

In OSX, with a valid text input field selected, you can launch the character viewer by pressing `Control` + `Command`+ `Space bar` or by selecting `Emoji & Symbols` from the `Edit` menu.

With that dialog opened, a search for `Prime` will display single, double, triple and quadruple prime symbols that you can click to insert.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201586